# How to create a XML file from an Excel in .NET?

Tags: c#

I want to create XML file from my Excel file through .NET (c#). My data is in Excel and it will be added in XML file.

Thanks.
Manoj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [good article in CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel2xml.aspx) about it. Generally the answer is, that Excel can be used as Data provider. Later, when you get data out, you can use XMLDom to generate XML file